# I am trying to get the XPath for a drop down

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the XPath for a drop down field which I can use in my Webdriver, Python code.
There are two drop down fields in the html.  I need to identify the drop down which has the options, Person Name, Organisation Name, Address etc.
I would like to select Address value from the drop down.

I have tried the following XPath:

```
//select[@class="gwt-ListBox marginbelow"]
```

It identifies both the drop down fields.

```
    <div class="clear">
    <span class="gwt-InlineLabel marginbelow myinlineblock" style="width: 8em;">Type</span>
    <select class="gwt-ListBox marginbelow" style="display: inline;">
        <option value="Person name">Person name</option>
        <option value="Organisation name">Organisation name</option>
        <option value="Address">Address</option>
        <option value="Date">Date</option>
        <option value="Email">Email</option>
        <option value="Phone">Phone</option>
        <option value="Integer">Integer</option>
        <option value="Numeric">Numeric</option>
        <option value="String">String</option>
        <option value="User-defined">User-defined</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="clear">
<div class="clear">
<div class="clear">
<div style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="clear">
    <span class="gwt-InlineLabel marginbelow myinlineblock" style="width: 8em;">TestDB</span>
    <select class="gwt-ListBox marginbelow" style="display: inline;">
    <option value="paf_uk15051">paf_uk15051</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

I will then use the XPath like this, e.g.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import select

data_objects_element_Type.Select(self.driver.find.element(By.XPATH, '//select[@class="gwt-ListBox marginbelow"]'))
data_objects_element_Type.select_by_visible_text(("Address"))
```

Thanks for suggestions.
Riaz

Comment: `//select[@class="gwt-ListBox marginbelow"]/option[@value="Address"]`  ?

Comment: You can take the xpath from root node. Both the select tags have same class name, if you select class name it will high light two drop downs. Post your HTML code from starting node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, I suggest editing the HTML, to contain ID's, so that you can specifically identify your two select boxes separately. If you cannot, here is a solution. I have made a jsfiddle site with your html-code, so that you can execute the script and see for yourself. The only thing you need to change, is the path, and choice of webdriver:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = WebDriver("path_to_webdriver")
driver.get("http://jsfiddle.net/ksftLk9j/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20, 2) 
wait.until(expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, 'result')))

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@class="gwt-ListBox marginbelow"]/option[@value="Address"]')
element.click()
```

the WebDriverWait, and switch_to_frame-statements are specific for this jsfiddle-case. The two bottom lines are not. You do not say anything about what you want to do with the element, but I'm gonna go out on a limb, and assume that you want to select it. Presto.

Answer (score 1):

You can try by checking the contains function. 
Like this:

```
 //option[contains(text(),'Address')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to find the element and perform click on it directly. This allows you to bypass the use of `Select` class

```
//select/option[@value='Address']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try it this way  :

```
  //select[@class="gwt-ListBox marginbelow"]/option[@value = 'Address']/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//select[contains(@class, 'ListBox')]/option[@value = 'Address']
```

So you code will be:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import select

data_objects_element_Type.Select(self.driver.find.element(By.XPATH, '//select[contains(@class, 'ListBox')]'))
data_objects_element_Type.select_by_visible_text(("Address"))
```

^ I don't know python, but you need method smth. like **selectByValue**